# AngularJS : Watch element.html() in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, markdown, angularjs-directive

I am looking to create a **mardown directive** (restrict A) which would make me able to use same recipient for **ng-view**. So I would basically load only .md files in views and apply my function on its content each time ng-view change. So :

**index.html**

```
<div markdown ng-view></div>
```

with two views containing, let say, **view1.md**

```
#That should be h1
```

and **view2.md**

```
##That should be h2, no ?
```

My actual code is

```
'use strict';
angular.module('btford.markdown', []).
  directive('markdown', function () {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(element.html(), function(value) {
                    var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(element.html());
                    element.html(htmlText);
            });

            var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(element.text());
            element.html(htmlText);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the question? What doesn't work?

Comment: Question is how do I keep my convert function applied to the content loaded through ng-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first param of watch can be a function, return any value you want including your $element.html().  You can even do a combination of data

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() { return $element.attr("abc") + $scope.variable + someinternalvar; },
    function(newVal, oldVal) { doTheStuff(); }
);
```

Obviously the more intense the data you put in here the slower your watches will be.  Use caution.

-- FYI

You should clean up your watchers, create an array and push the results of $scope.$watch into that array.  Then on the $destroy message remove them.  Also remember to unbind events as they will cause eventual performance issues as scopes are created & destroyed.

```
$document.bind('click', clickMe);
$(window).on("resize", winResize);

var watches = []

watches.push($scope.$watch("thing", function() { Thing(); }));

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    for (var i in watches) watches[i]();
    $document.unbind('click', clickMe);
    $(window).off("resize", winResize);
});
```

-- EDIT 2016-07-14

Just to add, cleaning up scope watchers is not needed as they are already processed internally, however rootScope, parent, etc. you should absolutely cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

It may be cleaner for you to use the `$stateChangeSuccess` event inside your directive rather than setting your own $watch. Try adding a callback function to the `$stateChangeSuccess` event, this should trickle down to the scope of your directive.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('btford.markdown', []).
  directive('markdown', function () {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // When the state is change to, or reloaded...
            scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
                var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(element.text());
                element.html(htmlText);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only watch variables on your scope.

```
scope.foo = 'bar';
scope.$watch('foo', function(newValue) {
  // Code to execute here
});
```

If you want to monitor the changes of DOM elements you need to do this on your own.

Comment: I want to monitor change made through ng-view to the content of my mardown element.

Comment: Actually that means watching the route... So I need to be able to watch route in my directive

Comment: Minor correction, you can not only watch scope attributes, as per your example, but also any function's output (`scope.$watch(someFunc, function(newVal, oldVal) {});`).

Comment: So... this answer is NOT correct. As Anton said, and I just tested it, you can do `scope.$watch(function(){ return element.html(); }, function(newVal, oldVal){ /* Code here */ }); and your function will get called whenever there's a change in the element's html.