# How to make angular linkify update when content changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm using [angular-linkify](https://github.com/scottcorgan/angular-linkify), and it's fantastic, but I'm having an issue where if I update the content of the linkify, it doesn't run the linkify filter again.

```
<label linkify>{{item.text}}</label>
```

then

```
item.text = item.text + 'more text';
```

...the text does update in the view, but it's not linkified.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590765/angularjs-watch-element-html-in-a-directive), I tried using `scope.$watch(element.html, ...)` and `scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', ...)` in the directive's `link` function, but the former produced an error and the latter wasn't triggered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the linkify service as you can see in the examples here: https://github.com/scottcorgan/angular-linkify

First of all inject into your controller these two services: **linkify and $sce**

Then, instead of doing this:

```
item.text = item.text + 'more text';
```

try to do that:

```
item.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(linkify.twitter(item.text + 'more text'));
```

Comment: Hmm, that might work... except that the value of `item.text` is used in lots of other places in the app (and stored on the backend, etc) so it needs to be text, not html. I'd like to be able to just trigger it to update...

Comment: You can assign the result of "$sce.trustAsHtml(linkify.twitter(item.text + 'more text'))" to another variable instead of item.text and solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Shabam, nailed it.

I modified the directive as follows:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    bind: '=ngBind'
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var type = attrs.linkify || 'normal';
    $timeout(function () { element.html(linkify[type](element.html())); });
    if (attrs.ngBind) {
      scope.$watch('bind', function (now, old) {
        if (now) {
          $timeout(function () { element.html(linkify[type](now)); });
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

and then the html:

```
<label ng-bind="item.text" linkify></label>
```